# Wordpress Multisite

Tags: multisite, web-services, customization

I'm building a WordPress website that will have around 50 smaller sites in it; *either a state with each county being the smaller site*.

Each site will be managed by a different person.

I've just started with multisite and was wondering if this is the best way to go or if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: What is your question exactly? May you please specify?

Comment: If you haven't yet, you should probably read [Before You Create a Network](https://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network), which may help you with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Multisite is your best choice, you can share plugins, themes and users between websites if you want, also you can have some plugins, themes and users retricted to some sites only. Also you can have top domains for every site into the multisite.

Answer (score 0):

tagging onto this question! i'm a county web guy and our departments, which have very full-fledged individual sites, are currently on individual installs; i'm thinking of bringing them into multisite. the benefits seem good - easy to manage themes and plugins, only one DB to maintain, etc - but the downsides certainly exist (especially the "if there's one site issue, it affects everything" thing). would you recommend multisite in my case?